# Change default value for "Today" button in Month Calendar Control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, calendar

I am making a calendar with a daily message. I want to program the "Today: 2014-03-29" button on the calender (when you click it, it goes to today's day) I need to be able to change the value of that button in code. I would like to be able to change the year to 2013 instead of 2014.

So ex. Today:2014-04-06 but i want it to display 2013-04-06 and go to April, 6 2013 instead of 2014. The picture is the calendar for reference. Keep in mind it needs to change the year for everyday so today it would be 2013-03-26 the  tomorrow it would be 2013-03-27.

[image]

Comment: So... you want to change the "today" value on the datepicker? May I ask why?

Comment: It is for my girlfriend. I want it to display a little message about a memory that we've had in the past for that day.

Comment: is this a WPF application?

Comment: @RadioSpace Yes. I am using Visual Studio 2013, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: nope. when you started your project did you select "WPF Application" or "Windows Forms Application"? or is this an asp website

Comment: @RadioSpace Oh the project is a Windows Forms Application.

Comment: check the answer grant submitted!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a property on the control that lets you set the preferred date.

```
monthCalendar1.TodayDate = new DateTime(2013, 4, DateTime.Now.Day);
```

You may want to do some validation, for things like a leap year. If it's Feb 29, 2016 and you try to set it to Feb 29, 2015, you'll get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Thanks saved me some trouble I was just starting to test some stuff. here's the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.todaydate(v=vs.110).aspx) for the msdn on `TodayDate`